# Should changing how data is seen be in the model or the view? (PHP - YII)

Tags: php, yii

I read recently in the MVC practices that almost all data related to querying should be in the model. However, I'm interested in whether, when you are using a foreign key to change the displayed name of the queried object that should be in the model or in the view.

Here is the example I am working with.

```
     // the id is being saved from the model 
$callfood=Food::model()->getfoodlist();
     // in this part $callfood is using a foreign key to display the 'food_id' as the   names of the food 
     echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'food_id',$callfood); ?>
```

It makes sense to me that the dropDownList code should be in the view, but I do feel like I am changing how it is shown/saved in the drop downlist. Should this remain in the view? or should this be pushed into the model so that I can reuse it if I want to change the view and keep the dropdown list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how your workflow is set up. But basically you save the model in a variable and send it to the view. You can then use dropDownList($model, 'food_id',$f_model->getfoodlist()). I recommend that you have a closer look at how PHP and Yii works ;)